# How do I exclude results with the .php file extension in Google search?

Tags: google-search

I spend a lot of time searching for resources about PHP. As the search narrows and the results get fewer, I begin to get a lot of noise from pages unrelated to my research, simply appearing there because they end with ".php".

If I do

> -".php"

it works, but also hides the pages that *are* relevant but end in .php

How do I search Google and ignore as relevant to my search, but **not** remove those entries containing ".php" from the results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`intext:php` or `allintext: your php query` may work.

Comment: Thank you so much. Works perfectly. I know I'm late in flagging this as answered but for some reason I did not get a notification(or rather, I must have missed it). Also, thanks for the edits to my question. It really needed them.